# Can't display runtime errors in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-2010, error-handling, web-config

I have some difficulties to display runtime errors in SharePoint, even if my web.config looks fine :

I have set:

- customErrors to Off
- CallStack to true
- `<compilation batch="true" debug="true" optimizeCompilations="true">`

Do you have any idea where the problem comes from ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Things changed a little between SharePoint 2007 and SharePoint 2010. Greg discusses the steps that are required to get detailed error messages in the following post:

http://www.greggalipeau.com/sharepoint-2010-customerrors-mode/